# Collection for below data structure

Tags: java, tree

I retrieve Country, State and City from the database. The query returns data in the format `List<Object[]>` where each object array contains Country, State and City.

I am thinking of putting this in a Tree collection, but could not find any good examples. Can anyone please help.

Is there a better solution of putting this data together. I need to traverse this data.

Example of query output:

- US-NY-Long Island
- US-NY-Queens
- US-NJ-New Jersey

My initial idea was to create 2 hashmaps. First would contain key=country and value=state and 2nd map would contain key=state and value=city. So now if I want to know the cities within US, first find values for key=US. Then taking the values of 1st map(NY,NJ) as keys for the 2nd map, I would return the cities from the 2nd map. Does this sound weird or is there anything better?

Comment: Please ,specify how exactly you need to traverse the data, so appropriate collection can be suggested (List, HashMap, TreeMap, etc)

Comment: why do you think you need a tree?

Comment: Are you looking for the most suited `Collection`to use ?

Comment: For example, if I pass the country, I need to get the states within it, followed by the cities within it. All 3 should be linked together. Not sure which `Collection` is best suited for this so requesting opinion from senior folks

Answer (score 4):

Create a class with `city`, `state`, and `country` properties, then return a `List` of that.

Comment: Will I get the list of cities, if I pass in the country by using this technique. Please suggest how..thanks

Comment: Will all three properties in the class be `List`? I am bit confused

Comment: @dazzle Those three properties would probably be of type `String`. You didn't mention any sort of access or iteration requirements, so I didn't address that. Based on your question and comments, I'm guessing you've got a lot more requirements than you originally stated. Try stating the whole problem up front, and give examples of ideas you've had for meeting them. Most SO users won't do your homework (or work) assignments for you, but maybe somebody will give you hints if you "show your work" so to speak.

Comment: My initial idea was to create 2 hashmaps. First would contain key=country and value=state and 2nd map would contain key=state and value=city. So now if I want to know the cities within US, first find values for key=US. Then taking the values of 1st map(NY,NJ) as keys for the 2nd map, I would return the cities from the 2nd map. Does this sound weird or is there anything better?

Comment: @dazzle It's probably still best for you if you create the `class` I described. Then implement `hashCode` and `equals` as other people have suggested. You can then create a `Set` that contains each city-state-country combination in your dataset. From there, you can use something like [Sets#filter][guava_filter] from Google's Guava project to extract just the ones you care about in any given scenario.

[guava_filter]: https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#filter(java.util.Set,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate)

Comment: @dazzle The approach I described minimizes memory footprint and work done while parsing the dataset (if it comes from a text file). It also makes it consistent to add additional filters on something you've already filtered. The tradeoff is that you need to do the work of filtering every time you read if you need different criteria (or if you threw away the old results).

If all you ever need is to provide the states in a country, and seperately, the cities in a state, then your approach of maintaining two `Map`s makes sense, and I'd use a `Map<Set<String>>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class with City, State, and Country properties, and override equals n hashcde method...

Along with that you must implement Comparable interface and override compareTo method in the class. As city-state-country will be an unique combination you can use TreeSet collection to add those records retrieved from the DB.

Comment: Thanks. Please suggest why I need to override equals n hashcode in this case. Any example would be really helpful.

Comment: It is a great practice to implement hashCode method. TreeSet is uses equals method to check whether 2 instances are equal... By implementing same class can be used with each collection API